# Angular - How to stop Http Error Interceptor from displaying the URL of my backend

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

In my Angular-14 project, I am implementing global http-error-interceptor.

I am this code:

```
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        if (typeof err.error === 'string'){
          this.toastr.error(err.error);
        } else if (typeof err.message === 'string') {
          this.toastr.error(err.message);
        } else {
          this.toastr.error(err.error.message);
        }
        const error = err.statusText || err.error.message;
        if (err.status === 0){
          this.toastr.error(err.statusText, err.status);
        }
        if (err){
          switch (err.status) {
            case 500:
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/server-error');
              break;
            case 422:
              this.toastr.error(err.statusText + ': ' + err.error.message, err.status);
              break;
            case 404:
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/page-not-found');
              break;
            case 403:
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
              break;
            case 401:
              this.toastr.error(err.error.message, err.statusCode);
              break;
            case 400:
              this.toastr.error(err.error.message, err.status);
              break;
            case 405:
              this.toastr.error(err.error.message, err.status);
              break;
            case 409:
              this.toastr.error(err.error.message, err.status);
              break;
            default:
              this.toastr.error('Something went wrong. Contact Adminstrator');
              break;
          }
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      })
    )
  }
}
```

I use toastr to display the error.

The issue I have is that, the interceptor displays two messages. The first is the real error (invalid credential), then the second is the URL of my api backend and 400.

When I console the error, I have this:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "https://localhost:44361/api/v1/login",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for https://localhost:44361/api/v1/login: 400 OK",
    "error": {
        "data": null,
        "successful": false,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "statusCode": 400
    }
}
```

This happens every time. It accompanies the real error with another one showing the API URL and 400.

How do I prevent it from displaying the url of the api backend?

> Http failure response for https://localhost:44361/api/v1/login: 400 OK

Thanks

Comment: But anyone can see your backend address anyway through the **Network** tab...

Comment: @Pieterjan - It looks odd for the URL to be displayed directly

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to create a `cons.ts` file as constant when you can write the code:

```js
login_url = this.environment.redirectUrl + '/login'
```

where you will import the **`redirectUrl`** from envronment.ts and in `environment.ts` you can configure the url like this:

```js
redirectUrl: 'https://localhost:44361/api/v1'
```

so that the error can show it like this:

```js
...
"url": "login_url",
...
```